# Is my Activity diagramm correct?

Tags: uml

This picture is a capture of my activity diagramm of the use cases consult:[image]

Comment: I can't see any picture.

Comment: Think you have missed  the diagram? If you can not add image directly, upload elsewhere and post the link here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is fine so far. However, you should add meaningful guards to the transitions coming from the decision node (though the activity names might already make that clear, but my French isn't good enough.